# Does Bison allow "?" in its syntax

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to write Grammar for java specification 
for example:-

```
COMPILATION_UNIT: PACKAGE_DEC? IMPORT_DECS? TYPE_DECS?
```

but it doesn't work 
I have the following error:

> invalid character: `?'

for each question mark I use in my `file.y`

I know that Bison has special characters and it should handle it

Please help

Comment: `grammar: token | ;` Now, include the symbol `grammar` in your main rule.

Answer (score 2):

As you have seen, bison does not implement the `?` regular expression optionality operator. Nor does it implement `+`  or `*` repetition operators. That's because the right-hand sides of productions in contex-free grammars are not regular expressions.

Yacc/bison context-free grammars do allow the `|` alternation operator, but as an abbreviation:

```
a : b | c
```

Is exactly the same as writing

```
a : b
a : c
```

and semantic actions only apply to the alternative in which  they are specified, so that

```
a : b | c { /* C action; */ }
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a : b    { /* Implicit default action*/ }
a : c    { /* C action; */ }
```

It is tempting to create `X_opt` non-terminals to capture the semantics of `X?`:

```
X_opt: X | %empty { $$ = default_value; }
```

In many simple cases that will work fine, but there are also many grammars in which that introduces an unnecessary shift-reduce conflict. Consider, for example:

```
label: IDENT ':'
label_opt: label | %empty
statement: label_opt expr
```

Since `expr` can start with an identifier, there is no way to know if an `IDENT` token starts a `label` or if it starts an `expr` following an empty `label_opt`. But LR(1) requires that the empty `label_opt` be reduced before the `IDENT` is consumed. So the above grammar is LR(2) and cannot be correctly parsed by an LR(1) parser.

That problem does not occur without the use of the `label_opt` shortcut:

```
label: IDENT ':'
statement: label expr
         | expr
```

Since the parser now does not have decide between `label` and `expr` before the `':'` is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Bison does not allow a ? meaning that the prior token is optional, you have to write out the grammar with the optional elements:

```
package_decl_opt: %empty
| SOME_TOKEN
;
package: package)_dec_opt TOKEN_PACKAGE TOKEN_IDENTIFIER
;
```

would allow both of the following:

```
SOME_TOKEN TOKEN_PACKAGE TOKEN_IDENTIFIER
TOKEN_PACKAGE TOKEN_IDENTIFIER
```